# Dependency issues while trying to upgrade 12.04.2 to the 12.04.3 HWE stack

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, kernel, dependencies, hardware-enablement-stack

While trying to upgrade my system to the latest [hardware enablement stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) from Ubuntu 12.04.2/Linux 3.5 I get the following error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-raring xserver-xorg-lts-raring libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-raring
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-raring : Depends: libglapi-mesa-lts-raring (= 9.1.4-0ubuntu0.1~precise1) but it is not going to be installed
                              Recommends: libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-raring (>= 7.2) but it is not going to be installed
 xserver-xorg-lts-raring : Depends: xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-raring but it is not going to be installed or
                                    xorg-driver-video
                           Depends: xserver-xorg-input-evdev-lts-raring but it is not going to be installed
                           Recommends: libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-raring but it is not going to be installed
                           Recommends: xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-raring but it is not going to be installed
                           Recommends: xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-raring but it is not going to be installed
                           Recommends: x11-xserver-utils-lts-raring
                           Conflicts: libglapi-mesa:i386 (>= 0~)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This appears to be a known issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-lts-raring/+bug/1191563). The bug report includes a [workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-lts-raring/+bug/1191563/comments/2) similar to the one proposed in [Bao Bui's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/336242/81372):

> After some trial and error the apt-get command that eventually worked
>   for me is:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install -V libglapi-mesa-lts-raring libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-raring xserver-xorg-lts-raring xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-raring libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-raring x11-xserver-utils-lts-raring libglapi-mesa-lts-raring:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-raring:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-raring:i386
> ```
>
> Make sure to carefully check the suggested changes before proceeding
>   to ensure that no essential packages are removed!

I can confirm that this solution worked for me.

---

On a related note: Just a small warning for anyone planning to upgrade using the HWE. This upgrade was far from smooth for me. Aside from all the dependency issues described in this Q&A, I had to manually install Raring packages to get my WLAN (broadcom) to work. Similar issues might arise if you have hardware that's running using proprietary drivers (installed via the "Additional Drivers" dialog).

So be wary when installing these hardware enablement stacks. It's a a feature that obviously still needs a lot of work.

Answer (score 2):

If there are some umet dependencies, you could try to add these dependent packages to your install command. For example, your install command could be like this:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-raring xserver-xorg-lts-raring libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-raring libglapi-mesa-lts-raring libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-raring xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-raring ...
```

I just upgraded to 12.04.3 and I had the same problem. In my case, there are a lot of removed stuffs after I issue the install command and sadly the upgrade breaks my ubuntu :-(. It took me ~1/2 day to make my system works with the new xorg stack. So be carefull if there are many removed packages :-).

Comment: This sounds very much like a variant of the bug I experienced when trying to install the 12.04.2 HWE on 12.04.1. The workaround back in the day was to install a couple if i386 packages. See [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-lts-quantal/+bug/1125413) for more information. It's very unfortunate that this hasn't been addressed yet apparently. Under these circumstances I think that I am going to follow your advice and hold off from upgrading for now.

Comment: Hi again. I found a bug report with a workaround similar to the one you proposed. It worked fine for me. You might want to check my [answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/336138/dependency-issues-while-trying-to-upgrade-12-04-2-to-the-12-04-3-hwe-stack/336913#336913) above for more information. Thanks again for getting me on the right track to solve this!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but just purged the quantal Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE):

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-generic-lts-quantal xserver-xorg-lts-quantal
```

I did not reboot the machine and installed the raring HWE:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-raring xserver-xorg-lts-raring
```

Some time into the installation there was a warning about an application crash. The installation continued and all raring parts seemed to get installed. After rebooting I checked the version of the kernel. Ubuntu vas the running the 3.5-kernel. I repeated:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-raring xserver-xorg-lts-raring
```

and the 3.8-kernel got set up. Everything else were set up the first time. It seems the application crash caused the kernel to not be configured the first time.